# Fourier transform of derivative of correlations

Tags: correlation, fast-fourier-transform

I am trying to obtain spectra of derivative of a two-point correlation. What I know is that spectra of two-point correlations are computed as follows

$\phi_{a{b}} = FFT(a) \times conj(FFT(b))$

where $\phi_{a{b}}$ is spectra of correlation of $a$ and $b$, and $a$ and $b$ are two signals collected at two different locations.

I also know that FFT of derivative of a function is

$FFT(\partial f/\partial x) = i \times \kappa \times FFT( f)$

where $\kappa$ is wavenumber and $f$ is a function.

My question is that is the following statement correct or not.

$\phi_{\partial a{b}/\partial x} =   i \times \kappa \times  FFT(a) \times conj(FFT(b))$

Comment: I've never seen the notation ϕ∂ab/∂x, and have no idea what it would mean.

I'm used to a two-point correlation function measuring how correlated two points are, averaged over time, and usually cared about for how quickly correlations decay with distance.  Usually they are a function strictly of how far apart they are.  The partial x would then be with respect to distance.  However, here the FFTs should be with respect to time.

Comment: Sorrry if I wasn't clear. $\phi_{something}$  means spectra of something. It is written in the question but maybe I wasn't clear enough. So basically I'm trying to obtain spectra of derivative of two-point correlations.

Comment: ϕ\_f cannot be the spectrum of f, because the formula you give for ϕ\_ab is not the spectrum of "ab", at least not if "ab" means the usual point-wise product.  Given the formula you have, ϕ\_ab is the spectrum[\*] of integral ds a(s)b(t-s).  (Fourier transform of convolution is point-wise product of Fourier transforms).

[\*] One of the many possible meanings of spectrum, anyway.  Though even in the Fourier sense, it more often means absolute value or absolute-value squared of the Fourier transform.

Comment: The only way I can sanely interpret phi\_ab as something generalizeable is if it takes two arguments, a, and b, that are confusingly written juxtaposed.  So how do I fit the "one thing" ∂ab/∂x into this?

Comment: I guess I am unclear about this. My background isn't math so I might be a bit lost. If a_1 and a_2 two signals are taken at different locations. a_1 = a(x_1) and a_2 = a(x_2). I want to obtain the energy spectra of a, so I use fft(a)xconj(fft(a)). I guess I should have said energy spectra.

Comment: Now, I want to obtain energy spectra of (d(a_1 a_2)/dx). I am a bit lost at this point.